# How to resolved the sudo issue it is not working ubuntu 16.0.4

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am new user in Ubuntu system and I want to Install-Up-work-Team-App I

Follow some step and downloaded a folder and extract then try to copy and past

usr/lib But i did not get permission to past folder into usr/lib folder so I

given permission using below command.

```
                         sudo chmod 777 -R /usr/lib
```

After that when I try anything sudo it not Working and I found error like this:-

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin `sudoers_policy'
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

I don't know how to resolved this type of issue.

Comment: Unfortunately there are plenty of files in `/usr/lib` that don't have `777` permissions by default, so finding these files and then reverting them back to their original permissions is a time-consuming exercise. The best solution really is to just make a backup of your own files, which should all reside in `$HOME`, and reinstall Ubuntu. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12998/wrongly-set-chmod-777-problems for example.

Comment: @edwinksl please help me solve the problem without reinstall ubuntu,do uyou have any idea about it

Comment: See the link I posted above.

Comment: @edwinksl ok, Thanks

Comment: It will definitely take less time to just reinstall than figure out how to fix the permissions. I don't often suggest reinstalling, but a wrong `sudo chmod -R 777` is one of those few situations that warrants it.

Comment: For your own good please follow @edwinksl's advice and **reinstall**. You will not be able to restore the right modes - take it as a given. It will then require an enormous knowledge of Linux to fix all issues which may pop up, ostensibly bit related to the files you changed. Just reinstall.